# Functional Testing Rails, No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, functional-testing

I am trying to fix the following rails functional test:

```
test "should create broadcast" do
  login_as(:one_details)
  assert_difference('Broadcast.count') do
    post :create, feeds: [:twitter, {alumni_email: 'test@email.com'}], broadcast: {id: 2, content: @broadcast.content, user: @user_details.user_id}
  end
  assert_redirected_to "#{broadcast_path}?page=1"
end
```

Here is the error:

```
1) Error:
BroadcastsControllerTest#test_should_create_broadcast:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"broadcasts"} missing required keys: [:id]
    test/controllers/broadcasts_controller_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:BroadcastsControllerTest>'
```

I have this in the routes file:

```
resources :broadcasts, except: [:edit, :update]
```

In the broadcasts_controller the show method looks like this:

```
def show
  if is_admin?
    respond_to do |format|

      format.js { render partial: 'show_local',
                       locals: {broadcast: @broadcast, current_page: @current_page},
                       layout: false }
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json # show.json.builder
    end
  else
    indicate_illegal_request I18n.t('not allowed to view this')
  end
end
```

The broadcast controller create method:

def create

```
  @broadcast = Broadcast.new(broadcast_params)

  # Wire up broadcast with the current user (an administrator)
  # Will be an admin user (see before_filter)
  # Note the current_user is a user_detail object so we need
  # to navigate to its user object
  @broadcast.user = current_user.user

  # Doing the next line forces a save automatically. I want to defer this
  # until the "if" statement
  #current_user.user.broadcasts << @broadcast

  no_errors = false
  respond_to do |format|
    if @broadcast.save

      # Only after saving do we try and do the real broadcast. Could have been
      # done using an observer, but I wanted this to be more explicit

      results = BroadcastService.broadcast(@broadcast, params[:feeds])
      if results.length > 0
        # Something went wrong when trying to broadcast to one or more of the
        # feeds.
        @broadcast.errors[:base] << ("#{I18n.t('broadcasts.unable-message')}: #{results.inspect}")
        flash[:error] = I18n.t('broadcasts.saved-but-message')
      else
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t('broadcasts.saved-message')
        no_errors = true
      end
      if no_errors
        format.html { redirect_to(broadcasts_url(page: @current_page)) }
        format.json { render json: @broadcast, status: :created, location: @broadcast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.xml {
          # Either say it partly worked but send back the errors or else send
          # back complete failure indicator (couldn't even save)
          if results
            render json: @broadcast.errors, status: :created, location: @broadcast
          else
            render json: @broadcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 assert_redirected_to "#{broadcast_path}?page=1"
```

to

```
  assert_redirected_to "#{broadcasts_path}?page=1"
```

also change

```
post :create, feeds: [:twitter, {alumni_email: 'test@email.com'}], broadcast: {id: 2, content: @broadcast.content, user: @user_details.user_id}
```

to

```
post :create, feeds: [:twitter, {alumni_email: 'test@email.com'}], broadcast_params: {id: 2, content: @broadcast.content, user: @user_details.user_id}
```

you are not passing an id in the redirect check so you either make it broadcasts_path

Comment: If you modified the line from where is it getting the? Page=1 that is not in my suggestion?

Comment: Did you save your test file?

Comment: Yes my test now looks like this: 
test "should create broadcast" do
    login_as(:one_details)
    assert_difference('Broadcast.count') do
      post :create, feeds: [:twitter, {alumni_email: 'test@email.com'}], broadcast: {content: @broadcast.content, user: @user_details.user_id}
    end
    assert_redirected_to broadcast_path(assigns(:broadcast))
    #assert_response :success
end

Comment: How are you running your tests? If the error message is the same then it's not catching those latest changes there is no ?page=1 showing in your error anymore.

Comment: Im running the tests from the command line using - rake test:functionals

Comment: ok i think i found the problem can you please change the line to   assert_redirected_to "#{broadcasts_path}?page=1"  ( with an s )

Comment: In your test change post .... broadcast to post ... broadcast_params that's what your controller is expecting to save

Comment: What so it should be - post :create, feeds: [:twitter, {alumni_email: 'jdbowen1994@hotmail.com'}], broadcast_params: {content: .......

Comment: yes that's what you are waiting for in your controller to save @broadcast = Broadcast.new(broadcast_params)

Comment: 1) Error:
BroadcastsControllerTest#test_should_create_broadcast:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: broadcast

Comment: Are you setting broadcast_params in a before filter?  If yes then please change it back there must be another reason for not saving and re rendering the new

Comment: Ok From what i see, The test itself is now working the problem is with the code, ie: the controller isn't saving and redirecting it is instead rendering the new form again, do you have any validations in your model ?